# how to write a IAM policy to give full s3 access but one directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to give all permissions on a single s3 bucket but a single folder. I am trying to use explicit deny the folder name being Beijing path is like
buck123-test/china/Beijing/. bucket name is  buck123-test.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1561641021576",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1561639869054",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test/china/Beijing"
    }
]
```

}

how can i achieve my requirement as the above policy is not working

Answer (score 2):

Your policy is missing `Allow` actions for objects in your bucket.

What about ? (not tested myself, let's report if this works)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1561641021576",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test", "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test/*"]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1561639869054",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test/china/Beijing/*"
    }
]

}
```

Note that you need the two resources.  The bucket name only resource is required for `ListBucket` and other bucket level operations.  The `/*` resource is required for object level operations like `Put` and `Get`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can still list the objects inside Beijing folder. with command         aws s3 ls buck123-test/china/Beijing/
can I also block this operation

Comment: good point, I don't think you can restrict ListBucket operation to a part of a bucket  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as Sebastien, you might just want to deny s3:*

Comment: will not work ... ListBucket API is like 'ls' command on a filesystem.  If you can read the directory, you can see all files in there, and you can not hide some files.  Seeing the files does not mean customer have access to file content.  I would suggest to use two buckets if you want to allow a ListBucket except some files. (but ask yourself : what are you trying to achieve? Is this really necessary to authorise ListBucket at all ?)

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer, you were missing some critical pieces to the policy document, try this as it should work, but I have not tested this.

You can add additional actions if you want to allow users to GetObject, PutObject etc.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1561648158487",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1561648106618",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test/china/Beijing/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1561648156125",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::buck123-test/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. 
But I am trying to explicitly deny access to Beijing folder. So the user should be able to do whatever on the bucket, but have no access to Beijing folder

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misinterpreted that part. I'll update the answer